# Why does Account Controls not work on the Ardor parent chain but only for child chains?

Tags: ardor, child-chain, account-control

Account controls that let you do account locking doesnt seem to show up on the Ardor parent chain. Why is this disabled while it works for the child chains? How does one secure their Ardor, if account control doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to NXT wiki:

> In Ardor, only child chain transactions can be phased. Therefore, when account control is set for an account, it can no longer submit Ardor chain transactions.

In other words: account locked for child chain is locked for Ardor chain to.

See for details: [Account_Control](https://nxtwiki.org/wiki/Account_Control)

Comment: if i can't submit ardor chain transactions. does that mean i can't do anything on the Ardor parent chain anymore? Even leasing? Or sending of Ardor to another account?

Comment: Looks like you can't do anything, even leasing. For being unable to send Ardor - wasn't this the purpose of "securing their Ardor"?